# How to stop VI from highlighting dollar signs

Tags: drupal, vi

I am editing PHP in `vi` and as anybody familiar with PHP knows there are a lot of dollar signs. It happens when that's how you declare a variable. However, `vi`'s syntax highlighting seems to think that the dollar sign is something strange and evil, because on every variable `vi` puts the dollar sign and first character in white-on-pink. It's very distracting on top of my black background.

I don't want to get rid of syntax highlighting completely. Is there any way to just stop the erroneous and obnoxious highlighting of dollar signs in `vi`?

Note: This only happens when editing Drupal code, which almost never ends in `.php`. Typical extensions include `.module`, `.install`, and `.php.inc`.

Comment: How are your files named?  Cause the standard syntax files for PHP are quite fine with dollar signs.  Either you're using a custom(ized) syntax file, or Vim doesn't think the file is the type that you think it is.  In the latter case, you can tell it what syntax to use by saying `:set syntax=php`; see if that helps.

Comment: Oh, wait...are you using Vim, or standard old-school `vi`?

Comment: Well...the PHP files are actually Drupal PHP files, which almost never end in .php. I really wish they did, but such is life. And I'm never really sure what's the difference between Vim and vi, because I don't think I've ever used not-Vim but it's always `vi` on the command line.

Comment: `:set syntax=php` worked. Now is there any way I can tell vi that `.module`, `.install`, and `.inc` files should be treated as PHP by default?

Comment: Vim does colors and syntax highlighting and such, and knows how to interpret mouse buttons and such; i'm fairly certain vi does none of that.

Comment: From what i'm seeing in the built-in stuff, you could possibly use a line like `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.module,*.install,*.inc setf php`.  (Note the lack of spaces around the commas.)  I'm not sure whether that will cause conflicts with existing autocmds for those extensions though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType module,install,inc set syntax=php
```

Comment: I created a file `~/.vimrc` and put that in there but it didn't set the syntax for me.

Comment: Did you restart vim or source your .vimrc?